# Get the hashchange event to work in all browsers (including IE7)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fragment-identifier, hashchange

I have some code (written by another developer) that is doing AJAX page loading inside of WordPress (e.g. no page reloads) when you click a nav item, AJAX refreshes the primary content area. My problem is that it's broken in IE7 and I have no idea where to start in terms of debugging.

The original opening lines were

```
var queue = 0;

$('document').ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashChange, false);

    // Define window location variables
    var windowHost = window.location.host,
        windowHash = window.location.hash,
        windowPath = window.location.pathname;
```

But I changed them to make the `addEventListener` conditional on the basis of whether that method was present or not.  Some research told me that the method is not available in older versions of IE (e.g. 7 in my case).  Also, the IE7 debug console was identifying that as an unavailable method, so that's pretty clear. I rewrote the lines as follows, but the code is still not working:

```
var queue = 0;

$('document').ready(function() {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashChange, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("hashchange", hashchange, false);    
    }
    // Define window location variables
    var windowHost = window.location.host,
        windowHash = window.location.hash,
        windowPath = window.location.pathname;
```

The full original script can be viewed in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Jc9ySvrb

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx) requires events to be prefixed with **`on`**.
- You've different capitalizations for the method. Change `hashchange` in `attachEvent` to`hashChange` to get the event to work in IE8.
- Use the suggested implementation to support the `hashchange` implementation for IE7- and other old browsers.

I have created a cross-browser implementation, which adds the `hashchange` feature to browsers, even those who do [not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange#Browser_compatibility) it. The fallback is based on [the specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-hashchange).

```
//function hashchange  is assumed to exist. This function will fire on hashchange
if (!('onhashchange' in window)) {
    var oldHref = location.href;
    setInterval(function() {
        var newHref = location.href;
        if (oldHref !== newHref) {
            var _oldHref = oldHref;
            oldHref = newHref;
            hashChange.call(window, {
                'type': 'hashchange',
                'newURL': newHref,
                'oldURL': _oldHref
            });
        }
    }, 100);
} else if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashChange, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onhashchange", hashChange);    
}
```

Note: This code is useful for **one hashchange event**. If you want to add **multiple `hashchange` handlers**, use the following method.
It defines two functions, `addHashChange` and `removeHashChange`. Both methods take a function as an argument.

```
(function() {
    if ('onhashchange' in window) {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addHashChange = function(func, before) {
                window.addEventListener('hashchange', func, before);
            };
            window.removeHashChange = function(func) {
                window.removeEventListener('hashchange', func);
            };
            return;
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.addHashChange = function(func) {
                window.attachEvent('onhashchange', func);
            };
            window.removeHashChange = function(func) {
                window.detachEvent('onhashchange', func);
            };
            return;
        }
    }
    var hashChangeFuncs = [];
    var oldHref = location.href;
    window.addHashChange = function(func, before) {
        if (typeof func === 'function')
            hashChangeFuncs[before?'unshift':'push'](func);
    };
    window.removeHashChange = function(func) {
        for (var i=hashChangeFuncs.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            if (hashChangeFuncs[i] === func)
                hashChangeFuncs.splice(i, 1);
    };
    setInterval(function() {
        var newHref = location.href;
        if (oldHref !== newHref) {
            var _oldHref = oldHref;
            oldHref = newHref;
            for (var i=0; i<hashChangeFuncs.length; i++) {
                hashChangeFuncs[i].call(window, {
                    'type': 'hashchange',
                    'newURL': newHref,
                    'oldURL': _oldHref
                });
            }
        }
    }, 100);
})();
// Usage, infinitely many times:
addHashChange(function(e){alert(e.newURL||location.href);});
```

Comment: The event listener is bound correctly now, but will not do anything in IE7, because it is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/hashchange). [IE8 do support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc891506(v=vs.85).aspx) the `hashchange` event though. For IE7, you have to detect hashchanges through `setInterval`.

Comment: Well you certainly earned your reputation here @RobW - thanks a million.  You just saved me hours, I honestly don't know if it's worth going through the whole `setInterval` thing.  Looks like a mega headache.

Comment: @Brian Quite easy to implement. Store the value of `location.hash` in a variable. Run `setInterval` with a small enough interval, say 100. In the `setInterval` method, compare the previous value of `location.hash` with the current value. If they're different, fire a custom hashchange event, and store the new value of `location.hash` in the variable.

Comment: @RobW - hey if I'm not a jerk for asking, can you show me what that looks like?  I think it would benefit other people looking at this question with the same IE7 incompatibility issue...

Comment: @Brian Added a solid cross-browser implementation. Throughly tested.

Comment: @RobW, solid answer.  Still not sure, though, why the top-voted answer isn't just "don't do this yourself, use jQuery" :D

Comment: @RobW Good work, but shouldn't you use `oldHref = newHref` **after** calling `hashChange`?

Comment: @RobG Why do you use `_oldHref`? Wouldn't it work calling `hashChange` with `oldHref`, and after that update `oldHref`?

Comment: @Oriol Imagine that the `hashChange` function throws an error. Then `oldHref` would never be reset, and the function be called over and over again. To avoid this issue, I store it in a local variable before using it.

Comment: @RobW Could you explain what is going on here please, specifically the need for hashChangeFuncs?

Comment: @IanLunn These [add|remove]HashChange functions offer an abstraction to bind the hashchange events. `hashChangeFuncs` is a list of registered callbacks, to be invoked when the hash changes.

Comment: Useful! Seems like in IE8 there is no newURL or oldURL though

Comment: @Joel You could remove the `else if (window.attachEvent) { ...}` part if you need newURL/oldURL in IE8.

Comment: @RobW I did exactly that. Just worth noting.

Answer (score 3):

[attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) takes on two params:

```
bSuccess = object.attachEvent(sEvent, fpNotify)
```

[And is needed for all versions of IE below IE9! :( See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)
]

This could work:

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashChange, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onhashchange", hashchange);//SEE HERE...
    //missed the on. Fixed thanks to @Robs answer.
}
```

Of course if it is possible, you should just use JQuery, since it encapsulates all this for your.

And as always there is a plugin out there:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: That's great, thanks for the tipoff.  Question: Even in IE7 JS debug mode, I'm not getting any errors from the function itself (only the `addEventListener` before I made it conditional).  Any other suggestions for debug?  I tried your code but still no dice... frustratingly, no errors either :/